# Html map object - on click part of map get id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user click part of map I try get id of this part.

```
<img src="images/mapa.png"  alt="" width="588" height="711" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" class="map">
  <area shape="circle" id="vrsac" coords="317,191,25" href="#">
  <area shape="circle" id="pancevo" coords="273,225,25" href="#">
  <area shape="rect" id="beograd" coords="195,247,251,276" href="#">
  <area id="lazarevac" shape="rect" coords="204,283,267,318" href="#">
</map>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".map" ).click(function() {
        alert("Click: " + this.id);
    }); 
});
```

Thanks

Solved

I add class to area tag.

```
  <area class="qwe" shape="circle" id="vrsac" coords="317,191,25" href="#">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. The first one is to use correct selector: you want to track clicks on `area` tags, not on some element with class `map`. So you code should be:

```
$("area").click(function () {
    alert("Click: " + this.id);
});
```

or the second, more efficient in terms of performance - delegate click event from inner `area` tags to parent `map`:

```
$("map").on('click', 'area', function () {
    alert("Click: " + this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your jQuery selector from

$( ".map" )
 to 
$( "area" )